# Getting Stale Element error in selenium python while navigating back on the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, staleelementreferenceexception

I'm trying to build my own web scrapper in python selenium for this website : https://wyszukiwarka-krs.ms.gov.pl/,

But when my code comes back from clicking an element,it gives this error : Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
Here this "for a_tag in a_tags:" loop is only executed 1 time and then it breaks.
PS: If I don't click any element and just do "print(a_tag.text)", then the loop runs till the end and prints all the content

Please help me with this, how to run it after navigating back

```
    for tr_element in tr_elements:
            td_element = tr_element.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
           
            if len(td_element):
                
                for td_content in td_element:
                    a_tags = td_content.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
                    
                    if len(a_tags):
                        for a_tag in a_tags:
                           
                            try:
                              
                                #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                                # Store the current URL to navigate back to it after going to the next page
                                current_url = driver.current_url
                                location = a_tag.location
                               
                                
                                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", a_tag)
                                

                                time.sleep(5)

                                # Find the elements on the new page
                                div_elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
                                div_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Nazwa')]")
                                name_div_element = div_element.find_element_by_xpath("following-sibling::div")

                                register_div_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Rejestr')]")
                                name_register_div_element = register_div_element.find_element_by_xpath("following-sibling::div")

                                number_krs_div_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Numer KRS')]")
                                name_krsr_div_element = number_krs_div_element.find_element_by_xpath("following-sibling::div")

                                date_of_entry_div_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Data wpisu do Rejestru Przedsiębiorców')]")
                                name_date_of_entry_element = date_of_entry_div_element.find_element_by_xpath("following-sibling::div")
                                translated_text = translator.translate(name_register_div_element.text, src='pl', dest='en')
                                # Navigate back to the previous page
                                driver.back()
                              
                                time.sleep(5)
                                td_content = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('td')
                               
                                time.sleep(3)
                                a_tags = td_content.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
                               
                                
                                

                               
                                time.sleep(5)
                                
                            except ElementClickInterceptedException:
                                print("Element is not clickable")
                            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                                print("Stale element reference: retrying...")
                                a_tag = td_content.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
                                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", a_tag)
                                time.sleep(5)
                               
                                driver.get(current_url)
                        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve doing this

```
a_tags = get_elements(....)
for i_a in range(len(a_tags)):

    a_tags[i_a].click() #or whatever you want to do

    #Do what you need to do
    ...

    #Go back
    a_tags = get_elements(....)
```

Comment: HI, I tried implementing this method, but even this is giving this error "Message: stale element reference: stale element not found" , when driver goes back to previous page.